# How to access to the value inside a Swing JTextField/JPasswordField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

I am pretty new in Java **Swing** development and I have the following problem.

I have a custom **LoginFrame** that extends a classic **JFrame** Swing class to create a login windows in which the user insert its username and password.

Inside this class I have something like this:

```
externalPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout("fill"));    
    externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"), "w 50%, wrap");
    JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);    
    externalPanel.add(userNameTextField, "w 90%, wrap");    
    externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"), "w 50%, wrap");
    // JTextField pswdTextField = new JTextField(20);
    JPasswordField pswdTextField = new JPasswordField(20);
    externalPanel.add(pswdTextField, "w 90%, wrap");    
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    // loginButton.setActionCommand("loginAction");
    loginButton.addActionListener(this);

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Button LogIn cliccked");    
        firePropertyChange("loginResult", false, loginResult);    
    }
```

As you can see I have the actionPerformed that is executed when the user click the **JButton loginButton** object.

Ok, my problem is: From inside the **actionPerformed()^^ method how can I access to the values inserted in my **JTextField userNameTextField** and **JPasswordField pswdTextField**?

What have I to do?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Declare your fields outside the methods or make them final and add a new listener loginButton.addActionListener(<here>);

Comment: you can not access until you stored?

Answer (score 2):

Declare `JTextField userNameTextField, JPasswordField pswdTextField, JButton loginButton`  as globel. Then you can get values like this..

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == loginButton){
         String name = userNameTextField.getText();
         char[] pass = pswdTextField.getPassword();
         // your remaining operation...
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean that I have declare my variables as static?

Comment: and what have I to to declare it as global?

Comment: Just declare them outside the method

Comment: just declare above the constructor and all other functions, and create object inside the constructor. so you can access from any function inside the class. As your above code you declare and create object inside the constructor or whatever. so these objects only visible with in the scope. so you can't get value in actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0):

For JTextField: jTextField.getText() ---> returns String

For JPasswordField: jPasswordField.getPassword()  ----> returns char[]